# Bad code on Apple sample code?

Tags: ios, memory-management

I've looked at the Apple "PageControl" sample project ([See here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/PageControl/Listings/ReadMe_txt.html)) and I see this function in the code :

```
- (void)loadScrollViewWithPage:(int)page
{
    if (page < 0)
        return;
    if (page >= kNumberOfPages)
        return;

    // replace the placeholder if necessary
    MyViewController *controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
    if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
    {
        controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
        [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
        [controller release];
    }

    // add the controller's view to the scroll view
    if (controller.view.superview == nil)
    {
        CGRect frame = scrollView.frame;
        frame.origin.x = frame.size.width * page;
        frame.origin.y = 0;
        controller.view.frame = frame;
        [scrollView addSubview:controller.view];

        NSDictionary *numberItem = [self.contentList objectAtIndex:page];
        controller.numberImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[numberItem valueForKey:ImageKey]];
        controller.numberTitle.text = [numberItem valueForKey:NameKey];
    }
}
```

There is something I don't understand.
If the test part `if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])` is true, then we have

```
controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
[viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
[controller release];
```

Then just after :

```
if (controller.view.superview == nil)
```

But, controller has just been released. I think it may work because controller is still in memory, but isn't this a wrong way of coding the stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the added the `controller` object into `viewControllers` that retained the object. Therefore, it is still a live object after they release it.

Is it wrong? Maybe, it requires knowledge of what `NSArray` does, but that's fairly common.

I would have done it like so:

```
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
{
    controller = [[[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page] autorelease];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
}
```

Comment: +1 to the idea of using autorelease. As it stands, the code is not only relying  on the fact the NSArray retains objects added to it (pretty common, as you say), but also depends on no other thread removing the object from the NSArray. (Admittedly, since these are UI objects, that's unlikely to happen, but it's still bad karma to keep using an object you don't retain.)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're right. If I were coding this I would have added:

```
if ((NSNull *)controller == [NSNull null])
{
    controller = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithPageNumber:page];
    [viewControllers replaceObjectAtIndex:page withObject:controller];
    [controller release];
    controller = [viewControllers objectAtIndex:page];
}
```

To grab a reference after releasing.

Or I suppose the other way would be to use autorelease instead of release.

Comment: @fluchtpunkt : I don't understand the reason of this downvote... This answer seems to be valid...